# Is the react-draggable not support on mobile platform?

Tags: reactjs

My code is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-esdfhm?file=buttons%2FMuteButton.js).

The p-in-p button of the MediaPlayer triggers the MiniPlayer component.

And the react-draggable package is used in MiniPlayer component.

The top-left button works on the computer; however, it does not work in the mobile device.

When I remove the <Draggable> tag from the MiniPlayer.js, the top-left button works on mobile again.

How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 10):

react-draggable works on mobiles. It seems onClick or onChange inside <Draggable> are disabled on mobiles (or on touch devices in general).

To make elements inside the drag component clickable, set as `cancel` the selector of those elements.

````
<Draggable cancel=".btn">
  <div>
  ...
  <button className="btn">click</button>
</div>

</Draggable>```
````

Answer (score 1):

`react-draggable` works on mobiles but it also disable `onClick` or any Clickable of all child elements of the draggable item, except `onTouchStart` and `onTouchEnd`. You can use `cancel` props but it also disable the ability to drag and drop.

Here my solution and more explain: "You can then handle the touchstart event to save the starting position of the finger and use it to calculate the distance to move when the user drags the div. When the touchend event is fired, checks if the travel distance is less than some threshold (e.g. 5px) to determine if the user is making a click call."

And here the code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Draggable from 'react-draggable';

const DraggableDiv = () => {
  const [startX, setStartX] = useState(null);
  const [startY, setStartY] = useState(null);

  const handleTouchStart = event => {
    const touch = event.touches[0];
    setStartX(touch.clientX);
    setStartY(touch.clientY);
  };

  const handleTouchEnd = event => {
    const touch = event.changedTouches[0];
    const endX = touch.clientX;
    const endY = touch.clientY;
    const distance = Math.sqrt((endX - startX) ** 2 + (endY - startY) ** 2);
    if (distance < 5) {
      console.log('Click!');
    }
  };

  return (
    <Draggable>
      <a href="#" onTouchStart={handleTouchStart} onTouchEnd={handleTouchEnd}>
        <div>Draggable Div</div>
      </a>
    </Draggable>
  );
};

export default DraggableDiv;
```